# Time from excel getting todays date

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I have a cell on my excel file that contains Time only, like:

13:30:00
17:30:00
08:30:00 etc...

The problem is: When I try to insert it into database or `echo` it, somehow it's getting todays date aswell...

So instead I get : 13:30:00
I'm getting: 2016-02-10 13:30:00

Obs: My database field is already set as `Time`.

Update:

I just found [This](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) saying that Laravel uses `Carbon` to convert all date/time etc...

Then I tried what says in the documentation:

My Model:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'H:i:s';
```

still the same error =\

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$time = '13:30:00';
$timeStamp = strtotime($time);
echo date('H:i:s', $timeStamp);
```

This code will output the time stamp in H:i:s format.